# At Azure AD B2C local Signup, "Send verification code" and the "Verify" (code) in subsequent screens?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to change the default email verification behaviour of my (custom) Local SignUp User Journey. I would like the user to first enter their email address and password (and a custom claim), then click a "Create" button. In the next screen they have to enter the verification code they received by e-mail and click the "Finish" button.

So the email layout is OK and the functionality of the buttons is OK. It's just that they should be on subsequent screens.
Is this possible?

Is this standard behaviour of the Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider?

Could I use the standard verification email or do I have to send my own emails?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to customize out of box policies which are available but you can write your own custom policies to achieve the desired results. Will suggest you to visit 
[Azure b2c custom policy overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom)

Comment: I have written this (custom) policy myself and I think the the "Send verification code" and "Verify" screen is created bij the "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" TecnicalProfile. But i'm not sure.. 

I want to know if I can place these buttons (and functionality) in subsequent screens (instead of one) by modifying my Custom Policy but still using the "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" TecnicalProfile, or that I have to build the whole "sending of emails and code verification" functionality myself.

Comment: I ended up hiding the "Create" button when the email is not verified. When the correct verification code is entered I show the Create button again. I think it's more clear, because of less buttons.